# How to apply CSS to XML in python?

Tags: python, css, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have an xml file that would I would like to parse (E.g. using lxml.etree) apply a set of css styles to, and then export.  For instance, the input would be this xml:

```
<root>
  <foo id="good">
    <bar class="bad">
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

and this css:

```
bar {
   color:red
}

#good {
   color: green
}
```

and the resulting XML would look something like:

```
<root>
  <foo id="good" color="green">
    <bar class="bad" color="red">
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

so that the effects of the css are represented in the attributes of the resulting tree.

I can do this in python, but I thought there might be a simple way to reuse existing libraries to make it much easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want custom XML attributes? Or do you really want a `style` attribute like HTML?

Comment: I'd prefer custom XML attributes, but I could get by with a single style attribute.

Comment: And I assume you want inheritance rules to factor in as well? (E.g., color is applied to inner elements unless overridden)

Comment: That is desirable, but not necessary.